# Send automatic email to user after wp_create_user

Tags: user-registration, wp-create-user

So, here is some code I came up with -- It works, but now I need it to send the username and password it generated to that email address automatically ?? Also the first and last name isn't recording ?? Thanks!!

```
require('wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');

$user_email = trim(isset($_POST['payer_email']) ? $_POST['payer_email'] : "");
$user_name = trim(isset($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : "");

$user_id = username_exists( $user_name );
if ( !$user_id ) {
    $random_password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_name, $random_password, $user_email );
} else {
    $random_password = __('User already exists.  Password inherited.');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this: `wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $random_password);`

Comment: "This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content", which I am sure you don't want. Please explain your answer, rather than simply post code.

Comment: More information on this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_new_user_notification

Notify the blog admin of a new user, normally via email and also send an email with login/password to the new user.

Answer (score 3):

There's the `user_register` hook, which runs at the end of user insertion and has $user_id as a parameter, you could leverage that to send the username and password, but you have to [`update_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) before you can get first name and stuff, so it might be better to do it at the end of the user creation and usermeta insertion.

The only thing creating a user does is insert the user into the DB, you need to use `update_user_meta()` to add the user values. [`get_the_author_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta) has a list of the default usermeta values, if you insert something with the key of one of those, it will show up in `profile.php` by default, otherwise you will have to extend the user profile to display it.

Also, just a note, it seems as though you're setting `$random_password` to a non-random value and also, probably more importantly, setting it AFTER it's been used.

Answer (score 0):

I would use wp_insert_user instead of wp_create_user so you can add as much user data as you like in the first instance. Check the Wordpress codex for all that you can insert. (wp_create_user simply calls this function anyway!) 
To send out the user login details you can call wp_mail($user_email, $subject, $message);
Of course you will want to set $message to include the username and password in the body of the message text.
Another thing, I think you can create the function wp_new_user_notification which is a pluggable function and is called on new user registration, you can put the mail function in that, I know plugins such as Register Plus Redux and Pie Register do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I Think this is you are looking for.
This will add first name and last name to user meta and send a mail to user about first name and last name addition.

```
 add_action('user_register', 'add_user_custom_meta');

function add_user_custom_meta($user_id) {
    $user_info=get_userdata( $user_id );
if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) )
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', $_POST['first_name']);

if ( isset( $_POST['last_name'] ) )
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'last_name', $_POST['last_name']);

wp_mail($user_info->user_email, 'User first and last name', sprintf('Hi we have added your first name :-% and last name:- % to our site.',$_POST['first_name'],$_POST['last_name']));
}
```